# Oacle SQL QUERY TO FIND THE CHANGED RECORDS IN audit TABLE

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

*Re-framing the question and the answer I have tried. PLS do not mark as duplicate, the earlier question had an answre(it did not work) hence i did not delete it*
I have a table ANC_PER_ABS_ENTRIES that has the following detail -

| PER_AB_ENTRY_ID | person_number | action_type | duration | START_dATE | END_DATE | LAST_UPD_DT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | 101 | INSERT | 3 | 01/10/2022 | 03/10/2022 | 2022-11-02T04:59:43 |
| 15 | 101 | UPDATE | 1 | 01/10/2022 | 01/10/2022 | 2022-11-02T10:59:43 |
| 16 | 102 | INSERT | 4 | 02/10/2022 | 05/10/2022 | 2022-11-01T10:59:43 |
| 17 | 103 | INSERT | 4 | 02/10/2022 | 05/10/2022 | 2022-11-02T10:59:43 |
| 17 | 103 | delete | 4 | 02/10/2022 | 05/10/2022 | 2022-11-02T22:59:43 |
| 17 | 103 | INSERT | 4 | 02/10/2022 | 05/10/2022 | 2022-11-02T23:59:43 |

This table is a history table and the action like - insert update and delete are tracked in this table. I want to create a query that picks up only the changes in this table by comparing the `last_update_date`.

Eg- for `person_number` 101 with `per_ab_entry_id` -- > 15 , the `action_type` is insert first, then it is updated and the `end_date` is changed.

so in the first run, 1st row is picked, in the second run, only the update `action_type` should be picked.

In case of delete, i.e. for `person_number` 103, the inserted record that was picked in the first run  was deleted. so it should be picked in the next run.

How can I use a lag function for this to check the previous run last update date and check if there is any change in `start_date` and `end_Date`, if there is an insert/update/delete, I should return the latest row. In case of delete, I should send the deleted row and in case there is a new row created for the same `per_ab_entry_id` then I should return that as well.

The output should look like this in the latest run-

| PER_AB_ENTRY_ID | person_number | action_type | duration | START_dATE | END_DATE | LAST_UPD_DT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | 101 | UPDATE | 1 | 01/10/2022 | 01/10/2022 | 2022-11-02T10:59:43 |
| 16 | 102 | INSERT | 4 | 02/10/2022 | 05/10/2022 | 2022-11-01T10:59:43 |
| 17 | 103 | delete | 4 | 02/10/2022 | 05/10/2022 | 2022-11-02T22:59:43 |
| 17 | 103 | INSERT | 4 | 02/10/2022 | 05/10/2022 | 2022-11-02T22:59:43 |

I have tried the below query but it is not giving any output-

```
with anc as 
(
select person_number,
absence_type,
ABSENCE_STATUS,
approval_status_cd,
start_date,
end_date,
duration,
PER_AB_ENTRY_ID,
AUDIT_ACTION_TYPE_,
         row_number() over (order by PER_AB_ENTRY_ID, LAST_UPD_DT) rn

from ANC_PER_ABS_ENTRIES
)

select N1.person_number,
N1.absence_type,
N1.ABSENCE_STATUS,
N1.approval_status_cd,
N1.start_date,
N1.end_date,
N1.duration,
N1.PER_AB_ENTRY_ID,
N1.action_type 
from anc N1,
ANC N2
WHERE 
N1.PER_AB_ENTRY_ID = N2.PER_AB_ENTRY_ID
   and n1.rn + 1 = n2.rn

AND ( n1.start_date <> n2.start_date
    or n1.end_date <> n2.end_date
    or n1.DURATION <> n2.DURATION)
```

MATCH_RECOGNISE WILL NOT WORK because of db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select   PER_AB_ENTRY_ID, person_number, action_type, duration, START_dATE, END_DATE, LAST_UPD_DT
from
(
select   t.*
        ,rank() over (partition by PER_AB_ENTRY_ID order by LAST_UPD_DT desc) rnk

from     t
) t
where    rnk = 1
   or    rnk = 2 and ACTION_TYPE = 'delete'
order by PER_AB_ENTRY_ID, LAST_UPD_DT
```

| PER_AB_ENTRY_ID | PERSON_NUMBER | ACTION_TYPE | DURATION | START_DATE | END_DATE | LAST_UPD_DT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | 101 | UPDATE | 1 | 10-JAN-20 22.00.00.000000 | 10-JAN-20 22.00.00.000000 | 2022-11-02T10:59:43 |
| 16 | 102 | INSERT | 4 | 10-FEB-20 22.00.00.000000 | 10-MAY-20 22.00.00.000000 | 2022-11-01T10:59:43 |
| 17 | 103 | delete | 4 | 10-FEB-20 22.00.00.000000 | 10-MAY-20 22.00.00.000000 | 2022-11-02T22:59:43 |
| 17 | 103 | INSERT | 4 | 10-FEB-20 22.00.00.000000 | 10-MAY-20 22.00.00.000000 | 2022-11-02T23:59:43 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vgs4J2Xf)